# wordpress database restore - broken link

Tags: database, backup

I've tried to play with db backup and restore but I am dealing with difficulties.
This what I've done:

I backed up database using cPanel option and got 8MB large SQL file.
Afterwards I installed new Wordpress in it's own new home. I accessed database associated with new installation of Wordpress through phpMyAdmin and dropped all the tables. Then I clicked on Import and choose to upload file from my Computer. After some time process reported it's success with over 200 queries executed. 
I checked the database and tables were really there with content as well.

Now when I tried to start my new WP instance with hope to get it populated with DB data I get a broken link error, like URL that I've entered doesn't even exist.

I tried to keep it simple so I changed new WP `wp-config.php` to direct to an actual database(not backup) but then I get the old site run with page not found error.

Let me point that I installed new WP instance in existing WP installation folder. I placed it in a new folder of course called `development`. That makes it:

example.com (being my live version)
example.com/development (testing version)

So testing version works fine with default install but once I change it's config file to overwritten database it gets broken, or when I change it to use main database(example.com) I get Page not found error generated by Wordpress.

Hope all this makes sense. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you probably need to go into the wp_options table and change the rows 'site_url' and the 'home_url' to match up with the new location. site_url is on the first page of the wp_options table, and 'home_url' is on the second page.

If you can access the wp dashboard those can be changed in the 3rd and 4th text boxes on the Settings >> General admin screen.

Comment: brilliant Ben! I wouldn't think of this in a million years.

Comment: another thing you might help me with Ben... I've done this in order to apply new theme to a site but only index page seems to be affected with new theme because as soon as I click on any content(page,post,gallery) I get redirected to original site. Any idea?

Comment: figured it out man. it had custom permalinks activated, so once disabled everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already figured it out for yourself - with the help of Ben of course - so I don't now if it is still relevant to point you to some extra information about getting a WordPress backup to work.

However, recently I had to migrate a WordPress site to a different server. Therefore I've written some memo's for myself that I thought might be useful for you too. You can find the complete article here http://cool-tricks.net/wordpress/backup-wordpress-to-localhost/

I'll be glad if this can be of any use to whoever this may read.